# Coredata insert - Crash with no stack trace

Tags: objective-c, core-data

Hi I'm trying to use core data to insert data using core data. I haven't been able to save my data. As my code stands right now the program crashes without a stack trace so I'm a little stuck

detailedViewController code

```
-(void) addobject{
    if(self.isEditing == false){
        MasterViewController *mvc = self.delegate;
        mvc.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
        [mvc insertNewObject: self.txtUrlAddress.text : self.txtUrlName.text :     
        self.txtUrlImage.text];
     }
}
```

MasterViewController code

```
-(void)insertNewObject: (NSString *) url : (NSString*) urlName : (NSString *) urlImage
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
    Event *urlDatabase = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
    urlDatabase.url = url;
    urlDatabase.urlname = urlName;
    urlDatabase.urlImage = urlImage;
    // If appropriate, configure the new managed object.
    // Normally you should use accessor methods, but using KVC here avoids the need to add a custom class to the template.
    //[urlDatabase setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"urlname"];

    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
         // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
         // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    int count = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Data base size is %d", count]);
```

}

Can anyone see the issue with my code?

Comment: Nothing in the error log?

Comment: MasterViewController *mvc = self.delegate;?????

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo can he do that ??

Comment: @Omarj Actually, yes that is valid.

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo what about Alloc & init ??? or loading the viewController from the storyboard ???

Comment: I cant see any error output being printed. I tried adding an stop at exception break point. it it stops at [mvc insertNewObject: self.txtUrlAddress.text : self.txtUrlName.text :     
        self.txtUrlImage.text]; and doesnt seem to progress onto the MasterViewController.

Comment: @user873684 check out and be sure that mvc != nil

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
-(void)insertNewObject: (NSString *) url : (NSString*) urlName : (NSString *) urlImage
```

you should write

```
-(void)insertNewObject:(NSString *) url urlName: (NSString*) urlName urlImage: (NSString *) urlImage
```

The rest looks fine I think.. Solved this your problem?